# Install package to specific location

Tags: apt

I want to install Steam for Linux. As I have only 256gb SSD and not enough space for games, I'd like to install it (and all it's games) to a USB3 flash drive.

How to do that? Preferably using `sudo apt-get install ****`. Haven't find a way to specify the installation location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the major problem is the size of the games and not the size of Steam.

Install Steam as usual on your SSD.
The Games are installed in `~/Steam/SteamApps/common/TITLE`

Backup the "common"-Folder and delete it. Then make a symlink to your USB-Drive like this:

```
ln -s /media/<usb-drive>/steamgames/common ~/Steam/SteamApps/common
```

Now the games should be installed on your USB-Drive.
I don't really know if it works, but you can give it a try.

Comment: I like that and will try it once I get everything working.

Answer (score 0):

Inexact duplicate of [How do I use a different drive as an installation location for Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226884/how-do-i-use-a-different-drive-as-an-installation-location-for-steam/)

It is not in general possible to change the install paths used by `apt-get`.

However, in this case, the Steam `.deb` package only installs a few bootstrap scripts. Subsequently running the Steam script actually downloads the application, which subsequently manages its own updates.

While as far as I know Steam doesn't offer you a choice of location at install time (it will go into `$HOME/.local/share/Steam`), you can subsequently move the install location or create additional libraries - see the answer above.