# How to get Team Fortress 2 on a flash-drive

Tags: google-chrome, steam, usb-drive

I would like to get Team Fortress Two on my Chrome-Book, but I don't have enough space on my hard drive, so I went to Wal-mart and purchased a San-Disk flash-drive, however there seems to be some sort of glitch and I don't know how to get Team Fortress Two! Please help, I have been trying for weeks, but know it can be done. And thanks in advance. Update, the Ubuntu I am using is 14.04 and also this is the problem I have. I can go on Steam all the way to the Team Fortress 2 download page, asking where you want to download it on, and when I click on my drive, it says that I already have three Steam Libraries but for some reason, it won't recognize these and I can't make a new one. If anyone knows why this is happening, but can fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? and how did you try to store in on the flash-drive?  What error did you get when you tried (ideally show us by editing the question & placing your command & resulting messages as part of your question)

Comment: I am currently running Ubuntu version 14.04 and I did to store in on the flash-drive. The problem is that Team Fortress 2 needs to be downloaded on the original Steam Library but my original Steam Library is on my hard drive, that doesn't have enough space. I don't know how to move my original Steam Library to my flash-drive and it can't be deleted. If you know how to move the original Library, thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount a new drive on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup), especially: you need to mount the flash drive in a subdirectory, then copy TF2 over to that directory, then boot with an external drive, then delete TF2 from your internal SSD, then reboot and mount the flash drive to where it originally was!  **:-)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a different drive as an installation location for Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226884/how-do-i-use-a-different-drive-as-an-installation-location-for-steam)

Comment: I did everything in How do I use a different drive as an installation location for Steam? Nothing worked.

Comment: None of the things above worked, please help me, and thanks in advance.