# How do I install program files on a separate partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, steam, installed-programs

Since I know next to nothing about how Linux actually works, I'm gonna need step-by-step instructions if you have any.

I have 2 partitions on my 32GB flash drive, an 8GB one for the full Ubuntu installation, and the 24GB one for all other files. I tried installing Steam when I first installed Ubuntu and there wasn't enough space for it and the installation failed.

This led me to believe that I need to somehow have the extra space a default for installation. I got steam from the "Ubuntu Software" program. If you need clarification on anything, please specify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a different drive as an installation location for Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226884/how-do-i-use-a-different-drive-as-an-installation-location-for-steam)

Comment: @DavidFoerster That's not what I was asking, so it's not a duplicate

Comment: In that case you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f` and `dh -h`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the linux directory structure applications are installed by convention. Depending on your distro and the nature of your applications, they are stored in /usr/bin/ /usr/local/bin/ /opt/ /home/ or others.

If you ran out of space you will usually want to resize existing partitions or mount some of these paths to a different partition.

In your case I would use a single partition with ext4 filesystem.